# $.each(someData.split(',') => returns concatenated string, instead of array of items

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm using asp.net mvc - ajax with jQuery...
I've a model type named "**Books**" that contains a property "**TableOfContents**"
this property contains data in the following format:

```
TableOfContents = "1,2,4,6,9,17,28";
```

Json action method, that reuturn Book object look like this:

```
public JsonResult GetBook(int id) {
    return Json(_bookRepository.Current(id), .....AllowGet);
}
```

Following style of list images that I want to display.

[image]

In C# (Razor) I can do this,

```
var splitted = Model.TableOfContents.Split(‘,’);
@foreach(var number in splitted) {
     <li><img src=”@Url.Content(“~/Content/Images/img-“ + number + “.gif”)” /> </li>
}
```

This code 100% works and shows images as shown in the above image.

The same thing I want to done with jQuery because I’m using ASP.NET MVC Ajax with jQuery. 
Here is the jQuery script through with I get data from MVC via jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">          
        function GetBook(id) {
            var url = '@Url.Content("~//Monthly/CurrentBook?id=")' + id;

            $.post(url,
            null,
            function (book) {
                $('#bookResult' + book.ID).html(
                '<a href="@Url.Content("~/BookDetails/")' + book.ID + '">Click to View Details</a>'
                + '<div><p style=" text-align:center;">'
                + '<a href="' + monthly.URL + '"><button style="background-image:url(@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/download-pdf.gif")); width:200px; height:70px;" /></a>'

+ '**<!-- Here I want to use jQuery Code for displaying Table of content Images -->**'

                + '</p></div>');                
            },
           'json'
       );
        }

</script>
```

I used jQuery code like this:

```
$.each(book.TableOfContents.split(','), function(number) {
  + '<li><img src="img-' + number + '.gif" /></li>'
}
```

But it displays result as:   "1,2,3,17,90" (in string format instead of displaying images)

In ASP.NET MVC Razor, I can display list of images like this:

```
  var splitted = Model.TableOfContents.Split(‘,’);
        @foreach(var number in splitted) {
             <li><img src=”@Url.Content(“~/Content/Images/img-“ + number + “.gif”)” /> </li>
        }
```

http://alhadith.cz.cc (this webite's main page displays list of images with ASP.NET MVC Razor)

Comment: That loop isn't valid JavaScript, it *should* be erroring, not displaying anything, can you post your actual code/behavior?...what's in the question doesn't check out.

Comment: Only one of your six other questions has received an acceptable answer?

Comment: I want to split TableOfContent property into different items (array) and want to show images through that items as I shown my C# (ASP.NET MVC Razor) example....that example works and displays images in the <li>...that splits string and each splitted item used in displaying different image....

Comment: please check http://www.alhadith.cz.cc (which shows what style of images I want to display- in the list)....

Comment: why would anyone want to increase the size of their javascrpit like this. why do we have spearation of concerns. since u r using MVC pattern cant you just return a partial view from the server for your markup and then dump it wherever you want..

Comment: The page where I want to use it is (http://aspspider.info/alhadithhazro/fulllist) where when user click a link, an ajax call get data and returns to the user in the BUbble Popup...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have

```
var book={TableOfContents:"1,2,4,6,9,17,28"};
```

as your object with data then in `<head>` add:

```
$(function(){

    $('#list').empty();
    var TableOfContentsSplit=book.TableOfContents.split(',');
    $.each(TableOfContentsSplit,function(number){
          $('#list').append('<li><img src="img-'+TableOfContentsSplit[number]+'.gif" /></li>\n');
    });

});
```

and in `<body>` add:

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

At the end you'll get:

```
<ul id="list">
<li><img src="img-1.gif"></li>
<li><img src="img-2.gif"></li>
<li><img src="img-4.gif"></li>
<li><img src="img-6.gif"></li>
<li><img src="img-9.gif"></li>
<li><img src="img-17.gif"></li>
<li><img src="img-28.gif"></li>
</ul>
```

Cheers
G.